# Is $f^{-1}(A)$ always rigorously defined even when $A$ is a set not in the codomain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. We know that $f^{-1}(y)$ is not always defined.

The codomain is $Y$.

**Can I say that $f^{-1}(A)$ is always well-defined unconditionally for an arbitrary set $A$?**

Do we need any topological assumptions?

For example, if $A$ does **not** intersect with the codomain, I can simply say that $f^{-1}(A)=\emptyset$. But when I check the textbook definition for "inverse image function" they always require $A\subseteq Y$. I need reference for the case when $A$ is not in $Y$.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the use of codomain and range. While range is sometimes ambiguous, unless there is some regional difference I think $Y$ should be the codomain.

Comment: $f^{-1}(A)$ is the set of elements $x$ of $X$ such that $f(x) \in A$. This set is well-defined for any subset $A$ of $Y$, and can be empty (as you mention in your last sentence).

Comment: Topology has nothing to do with this. Those concepts are purely from set theory.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Ok so if $A$ does not intersect with the codomain, is $f^{-1}$ still well-defined?

Comment: In no notation does it make sense to talk about $f^{-1}(A)$ if $A$ is not a subset of codomain of $f$. It would be like asking for the value of the greatest integer less than or equal function (which is defined for all reals) at the complex number $i$.

Comment: Short answer: no, $f^{-1}(A)$ is not defined when $A$ is not a subset of the codomain of $f$. You ask for references but i doubt there is one because the concept is useless as far as I can see. What other answer do you want? Are you asking for a way to define it? You could define it to be the empty set, but this would not be standard and it would just make whatever you are writing harder to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have fallen victim to notational abuse, unfortunately.

A function $f\colon X \to Y$ always determines two functions:

1. The "direct image function" $\mathsf{f}\colon P(X)\to P(Y)$ (where $P(S)$ is the power set of $S$, the set of all subsets of $S$), which is defined as follows: given a subset $A\subseteq X$, we have
   $$\mathsf{f}(A)=\{y\in Y\mid \text{there exists }a\in A\text{ such that }f(a)=y\}.$$
2. The "inverse image function", $\mathscr{F}\colon P(Y)\to P(X)$, defined as follows: given a subset $B\subseteq Y$, we let
   $$\mathscr{F}(B)=\{x\in X\mid \text{there exists }b\in B\text{ such that }f(x)=b\}.$$

By *abuse of notation*, we often denote the direct image function $\mathsf{f}$ with the same symbol as the original function (here $f$), and write
$$f(A) = \{f(a)\mid a\in A\}.$$
And also by abuse of notation, we often denote the inverse image function $\mathscr{F}$ by "$f^{-1}$" (even though this should be restricted to the inverse *function* and only used when $f$ has an inverse, i.e. is bijective), and write
$$f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in B\}.$$

To compound the abuse even more, when $A=\{a\}$ is a singleton, we write $f(a)$ instead of $f(\{a\})$, and rely on context to tell us if we mean the value of $f$ at $a$ or the direct image of the singleton. Likewise (and also in an exhibition of abuse upon abuse) if $B=\{b\}$ is a singleton, we write $f^{-1}(b)$ instead of $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ instead of $\mathscr{F}(\{b\})$ . To make matters even worse, sometimes when $f$ is injective but not surjective, we also use $f^{-1}$ to denote the inverse of the related (but under some formalisms, technically different from $f$) function $f\colon X\to f(X)$.

It is the latter abuse of abuse of abuse of notation which makes you say that sometimes "$f^{-1}(y)$ is not defined", and leads some to reply "no, it *is* defined, it is all elements that map to $y$, and could be empty."

So, the *inverse image function* is defined at *every* subset of $Y$ and gives a (possibly empty) subset of $X$. The *inverse function* may or may not exist, or be defined at specific elements.

This abuse can be confusing and unfortunate when you are just starting. It is a good idea, at that time, to be very careful to make sure there is no confusion. As you gain experince and comfort, the notational abuse is rather convenient and not confusing, which is why it is so prevalent.

But in no notation, abusive or otherwise, does it make sense to talk about $f^{-1}(Z)$ if $Z$ is not a subset (or an element) of $Y$. It's like asking for the floor of $1+i$, $\lfloor 1+i\rfloor$, a nonsensical question. You could, as Severin Schraven suggest in comments, further abuse notation even more (is there any kind of shelter for abused notations to escape to where they can be safe?) and simply think of $f^{-1}(Z)$ as "the set of all $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\in Z$, so that elements of $Z$ that are not in $Y$ will be irrelevant, but still write it and say it is "defined" (rather abusively...)

Comment: While I agree that it is technically not defined, I would definitely parse this differently with an even stronger abuse of notation. Namely, replacing $f$ by $g:X\rightarrow Y\cup A$ s.t. $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Very detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

The inverse image of an element $y$ under a function $f$ is defined to be the set of elements that are mapped to $y$ under $f$. If the set $A$ is disjoint from the range of $f$, then there are no elements of our set that are mapped to an element of $A$ so the inverse image of $A$ is empty by definition. No topological assumptions are needed since the definition is really just dependent on the function you are thinking about.

Comment: I basically agree with your statement. But when I check the text book definition of "inverse image function" they always require $A\subseteq Y$. I need reference for the case when $A$ is not in $Y$.

Comment: @HighGPA I believe you are mixing up the range and the codomain, as @ AlanAbraham mentioned in their comment. If we define a map $f: X \to Y$, the codomain of $f$ is $Y$ and the range of $f$ is $f(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that $f^{-1}$ maps on the power sets $\wp(Y)\to\wp (X)$.

And it has properties as
$$f(f^{-1}(A))\subseteq A,$$
for each $A$ subset of $Y$
and $$B\subseteq f^{-1}(f(B)),$$
for each $B$ subset of $X$, among others.

Comment: I agree with your statement though I'm a bit more interested in the case when $A$ is not in $\wp(Y)$.

Comment: @HighGPA the map is $$A\mapsto f^{-1}(A),$$ that is, $A\subseteq Y$ got assigned $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq X$ .

Comment: @HighGPA by definition $$f^{-1}(A)=\{x\in X\  | \ f(x)\in A\},$$ needs $A\subseteq Y$.

Comment: if $A$ is not a set on $Y$, where $f$ maps from $X$, it is a nothing to do